# spring boot security with vaadin Could not navigate to ''

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin10

I am just trying to do a learning exercise with Vaadin 10 and Spring boot. I added Sprint Security as well so the demo prompts for a user name and password. However when I type them correctly the browser just shows:

```
Could not navigate to ''
Reason: Couldn't find route for ''
Available routes:
This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode.
```

I rather hoped to see a button with 'click me' on it.

My MainView class is:

```
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView() {
        add(new Button("Click me", e -> Notification.show("Hello Spring+Vaadin user!")));
    }
}
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().formLogin();
     }

     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("test").roles("USER");
     }

     @Bean
     public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
     }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks very much.

Mark.

Comment: Can you provide a link for the learning exercise?

Comment: @Boris It was [Creating CRUD UI with Vaadin](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/). I have only done the basic elements, but I did include Spring Security when I created my Eclipse project (that is not part of the exercise). My understanding is then that this enables security. I then implemented my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter using other examples and posts, and then got stuck as above. Thanks.

Comment: I just build the project as per your description and can run it fine. Maybe there is a problem with dependencies? Can you add the POM file to the question?

Comment: @Boris I have investigated further this morning and created another test project without JPA or security and I still get the same problem. From my limited understanding I think that Spring-boot is not picking up my Route annotation in my MainView class. My main application class is the one created by Spring and includes the SpringBootApplication annotation. I have not changed anything in that class. My (latest) POM file is:

Comment: @Boris Here is my (latest) [POM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TBe4QmYQ0lNK3Z9QH-EkDfccOYJTP9wu/view?usp=sharing) file (anonymized).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help I received. I have found the simple mistake I made in that I put my MainView class in a sub package (called gui). When I moved it to the same package the as the main application class it then worked fine. Apologies and grateful thanks.

Comment: Good. I should have asked for the directory layout first.